# Not showing order tab at customer details page in admin panel

Tags: magento2, customer-account, admin-panel, customer-address, address-attribute

Few tab like (Orders, Product Reviews, Billing Agreements, Newsletter, Wish List, etc...) are not showing in customer details page in admin panel after magento2 upgrade.

All above tab's are showing at frontend side but not showing in admin panel.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your logs in var/log/ to see if there's an error reported?

Comment: yes, not showing any error in log files

Comment: Have you overwrite xml like customer_index_orders or customer_index_productreviews?

Comment: no, i haven't overwrite such xml files